# Posting a static message on facebook wall from FB application

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook application and i want to post a message from the application directly to the wall by calling a php script from my flex application.
Can you please help me out.

```
function postmessage($appid) {
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'XXX',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
        'cookie' => true
    ));
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    $attachment = array(
        'message' => 'this is my message',
        'name' => 'This',
        'caption' => 'Caption of the Post',
        'link' => 'apps.facebook.com/tvtreasurehunt/',
        'description' => 'this is a description'
    );
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to post a message using the php sdk. Actually i have a flex application and then i call a webservice in which i want to post a message to the wall of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a post on the user's wall. Prerequisite: you need to have a valid access_token with publish_stream permission.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  "http" => array(
    "method"    => "POST",
    "content"   => http_build_query(array(
      "access_token"    =>      $access_token,
      "link"            =>      $config["fb_app_url"],
      "name"            =>      "name",
      "description"     =>      "description",
    )),
  ),
));

file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed", false, $context);
```

For more detailed information see the official documentation: [Post on Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Comment: Can you please provide me the entire source code help to get the access_token and even set the permissions.

Comment: It's not that easy, here's the documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/